# How do I recover my pantheon session? Its not shown in the login?

Tags: release-freya, gala

I accidentally uninstalled gala from another wm (i3wm) in my freya. What are the `.desktop` and session files contents to recover the pantheon session??

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install gala`?